# Kafka partition assignment protocol

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am writing integration tests to validate a kafka producer consumer configuration using confluent-dotnet (which wraps librdkafka).

In one test I want to start up a consumer, who will start at the end of an existing partition, then publish a message from a producer and assert that the consumer has only consumed one message.

Now the startup of the consumer is asynchronous (ie: if you call subscribe then publish straight away, the consumer starting at the end won't receive it).
What is the appropriate way to code this test without race condition? Once I have done "Partition.Assign", is the consumer offset already decided? I am not sure because the callback of OnPartitionAssigned only contains a TopicPartition and no offset.

And on a related matter, it seems that sometimes, in the absence (afaict) of any kafka node failure, I received more partitions assigned than there are partitions (ie: I get assigned the same one twice), how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up an OnPartitionEof delegate which will be called when the consumer reaches the end of a partition, when it gets called you can be sure the consumer is indeed fetching messages for the given partition and you can start producing to it.

```
        consumer.OnPartitionEOF += (_, end)
            => Console.WriteLine($"Reached end of topic {end.Topic} partition {end.Partition}, next message will be at offset {end.Offset}");
```

Comment: Thanks, probably a good way to do it if using auto.reset property. At the moment I am doing something in the OnPartitionAssigned where I explicitly start consuming from a given offset thanks to the information from "QueryWatermarkOffsets" and/or "QueryCommittedOffsets".